# Getting NullReference Exception when trying to set this.Response.Headers

Tags: c#, header, httpresponse, response-headers

I have to set the "client-id" header in the API response.

I have below controller function which is implemented in a class `ProtectionControllerBase`.

```
"PolicyControllerBase : BaseClass"
"BaseClass : ControllerBase"
```

The controller base class is inherited by the `ProtectionControllerBase`:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> CreatePolicy<T>(T input) where T : PolicyBase
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    ProtectionPolicyBase resultPolicy = null;
    try
    {
        resultPolicy = await policyManager.CreatePolicy<PolicyBase>(input);
        return Created(resultPolicy); 
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
          return new ObjectResult()
          {
               StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError
          };
    }
    finally
    {
        stopwatch.Stop();
        messageLogger.LogDebug(enhancedRestoreContext, $"Time taken to finish creating policy :{stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
    }
}
```

I have to set the `"client-id"` header in the response.
To do the same, I added one additional function in the `BaseClass`:

```
protected void PopulateRequestIdHeader(string functionName)
{
    // populate request-id header with guid value
    string requestId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    messageLogger.LogDebug(context, $"Populating request-id header for {functionName} function with {requestId}");
    
    // Add Null Checks
    this.Response.Headers.Add("request-id", requestId);
}
```

And Changed the above function to make use of `PopulateRequestId` function:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> CreatePolicy<T>(T input) where T : PolicyBase
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    ProtectionPolicyBase resultPolicy = null;
    try
    {
        PopulateRequestIdHeader(nameof(CreatePolicy));
        resultPolicy = await policyManager.CreatePolicy<PolicyBase>(input);
        return Created(resultPolicy); 
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
          return new ObjectResult()
          {
               StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError
          };
    }
    finally
    {
        stopwatch.Stop();
        messageLogger.LogDebug(enhancedRestoreContext, $"Time taken to finish creating policy :{stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
    }
}
```

But this time when I call the API, I got the below exception:

[image]

I am not able to understand why this error is coming.

What my current understanding is, is that the ProtectionControllerBase object is created when the call to the API is made. So "this" keyword refers to current object of type "ProtectionControllerBase". It belongs to ControllerBase parent class, so it has "Response".

And so to set the header we can make use of

```
this.Response.Headers.Add("request-id", requestId);
```

But doing the same gives exception. I am not able to understand the reason. I have referred places to see how to set the headers and they kind of make use of similar code.

Comment: Please post a minimal, reproducible example, including controller code.

Comment: What happens when you do `Response.Headers.Add(...)` directly in `CreatePolicy()`?

Comment: Actually, I was running the test case when this exception was coming. When the actual API was run, it set the headers. Later got to know that in test case HttpContext is null and because of that this behaviour is happening.